# Edit for a page is not offered even though I have admin privileges

Tags: confluence, confluence-rest-api, confluence-macros, confluence-forge

I am an admin on Confluence and I cannot edit a page although I have all the possible privileges as shown in the screenshots attached. I think it is a bug, why is this happening and how can this be solved?[image]

[image]

the privilege for editing is ON but the edit button is not visible as shown in the screenshot above:
[image]

Comment: it can be better to address https://community.atlassian.com/ to find answers for such question. You need to read about how Permissions work to correctly set them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of restricted page is a red lock icon. click on it and give edit access to yourself.
You should do this on all parent pages of restricted page in page tree.
[restriction pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Qni.png)

Comment: I have the edit privileges when clicking on the restricted button but the edit button is still not visible on the page. I have added a screenshot above.

Comment: I can't see your screen shot but I think you should check parent page and give your self edit privilege. do it all the way till the space home page

Comment: also you can go to the space tools-> permissions->restricted pages-> and remove all restriction by clicking on lock icon